# how to use method inside an object in scala?

Tags: scala, object

I have this sample code in a scala worksheet. I do not understand why I can not access to the functions as at the bottom of the code.

```
object chapter5 {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  trait Stream2[+A] {
    def uncons: Option[(A, Stream2[A])]
    def isEmpty: Boolean = uncons.isEmpty
  }
  object Stream2 {

    def empty[A]: Stream2[A] =
      new Stream2[A] { def uncons = None }

    def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream2[A]): Stream2[A] =
      new Stream2[A] {
        lazy val uncons = Some((hd, tl))
      }

    def  apply[A](as: A*): Stream2[A] =
      if (as.isEmpty) empty
      else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }

  val s = Stream2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    s.isEmpty //I can access to the function declared in the trait
    s.cons // error  // I can not access to the function declared in the object
}
```

In addition I need to write the toList method. Where should I write it?  How can I test it if I can not access to the methods ?

Comment: I do not know what this code exactly does, but `s` is a `Stream2[Int]` instance while `cons` is a companion object method (you can use it with `Stream2.cons`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cons` is not part of the `Stream2` instance. It is a singleton(static) method of the `Stream2` object. So, the only way to access it is by calling it through the object:

```
Stream2.cons(2,s)
```

To access methods on the instance, you would have to add it to the `trait` (since it is referencing the trait and not the final object created). Otherwise, you could add it to the singleton and call it through that.

Comment: can I use cons inside the Stream2 object? the method apply seems to be using it.